# Getting an undefined reference to for an operator of < function

Tags: c++, boolean, operators

new to c++

Before I start yes this is homework, usually I can figure things out alright on my own but I'm not getting any actual errors on specific lines so this one is tough for me.

My code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class JobBid{

    private:
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const JobBid&);
        int bid;
        int quote;



    public:
        JobBid& operator() (int, int);
        bool operator<(const smallest)
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const JobBid& baq){

    out << "Bid #: " << baq.bid << " Quote $: " << baq.quote << endl;
    return out;
}

JobBid& JobBid::operator()(int b, int q){

    bid = b;
    quote = q;
}



int main()
{

    int b1;
    int b2;
    int b3;
    int b4;
    int q1;
    int q2;
    int q3;
    int q4;

    int smallestbid;
    int smallestquote;

    const int size = 4;
    JobBid JBArray[size];

    cout << "Enter the bid number for the first bid:" << endl;
    cin >> b1;

    cout << "Now enter the quote price for the first bid:" << endl;
    cin >> q1;

    cout << "Enter the bid number for the second bid:" << endl;
    cin >> b2;

    cout << "Now enter the quote price for the second bid:" << endl;
    cin >> q2;

    cout << "Enter the bid number for the third bid:" << endl;
    cin >> b3;

    cout << "Now enter the quote price for the third bid:" << endl;
    cin >> q3;

    cout << "Enter the bid number for the fourth bid:" << endl;
    cin >> b4;

    cout << "Now enter the quote price for the fourth bid:" << endl;
    cin >> q4;

    JBArray[1](b1, q1);
    JBArray[2](b2, q2);
    JBArray[3](b3, q3);
    JBArray[4](b4, q4);

    cout << JBArray[1] << JBArray[2] << JBArray[3] << JBArray[4] << endl;

    JobBid smallest = JBArray[0] ;
    for ( int i=1;  i < sizeof(JBArray)/sizeof(JBArray[0]);  ++i )
        if ( JBArray[i] < smallest )
             smallest = JBArray[i] ;

    cout << smallest << '\n' ;

}
```

I know the code is probably really bad but its an intro class. Either way I'm trying to return the smallest value of my created array list at the end of the main. However I found that trying to use the '<' operator on my type 'JobBid' created errors, so I looked around and found out that you have to define it yourself I guess.

I tried to do so here:

```
bool operator<(const smallest)
```

but I must be doing it wrong, I was able to get all errors out after that (errors on specific lines I mean) except now I'm getting this:

```
undefined reference to `JobBid::operator<(JobBid)'
```

and I'm not sure how to fix it. I think the logic for finding the smallest object in the array is right, so it must be something with the less than sign.

Comment: Do you have a definition of that overloaded operator?

Comment: I guess I don't, how would I define it? Am I suppose to be taking in smallest as the argument in the first place? I suppose I would need to do something like this:

JobBid& operator<(){

// but what would go here?

}

Comment: I see , you try to compare "JBArray[i] < smallest". You need to implement oparation for it.

Comment: Can't be your [MCVE] due to missing semicolons.

Comment: Also, looks far from minimal with all that text and eight variables `b1` to `q4`.

Comment: BTW, you should move your `operator<<` to the `public` section so users of your class can use the function.  As declared `private`, only methods in your class can use the `operator<<` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your method declaration is missing a type; you tell it the variable name and that its constant, but not the type.  Try this:

```
bool operator<(const JobBid& jb) const
{
    return (bid < jb.bid) && (quote < jb.quote);
}
```

I recommend adding the `const` at the end of the method to tell the compiler and readers that the method is not changing any of the data members.

**Edit 1**
The method should be added to the class:

```
class JobBid
{
    private:
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const JobBid&);
        int bid;
        int quote;
    public:
        JobBid& operator() (int, int);
        bool operator<(const JobBid & jb) const
        {
          return (bid < jb.bid) && (quote < jb.quote);
        }
};
```

**Edit 2: Implementation outside the class**

```
    class JobBid
    {
        private:
            friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const JobBid&);
            int bid;
            int quote;
        public:
            JobBid& operator() (int, int);
            bool operator<(const JobBid & jb) const;
    };

bool JobBid::operator<(const JobBid & jb) const
{
    return (bid < jb.bid) && (quote < jb.quote);
}
```

**Edit 3: Free standing function**

```
        class JobBid
        {
            private:
                friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const JobBid&);
                int bid;
                int quote;
            public:
                JobBid& operator() (int, int);
                friend bool operator<(const JobBid & a,
                                      const JobBid & b);
        };

bool operator<(const JobBid & a, const JobBid & b)
{
    return (a.bid < b.bid) && (a.quote < b.quote);
}
```

Comment: returns these errors:
26:34: error: non-member function 'bool operator<(const JobBid&)' cannot have cv-qualifier
26:34: error: 'bool operator<(const JobBid&)' must take exactly two arguments

Comment: Where did you declare it, inside the class or outside?  Defining the operator inside the class uses 1 parameter.  Declaring the function outside the class requires 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definition for the overloaded `<` operator. Since this is homework, I will not tell you exactly how to do it, but it should be very similar to overloaded operators you already have defined. Try looking at this website: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/96-overloading-the-comparison-operators/

Also, the declaration is not quite right. Instead of

```
bool operator<(const smallest)
```

it should be

```
friend bool operator<(const JobBid &left, const JobBid &right);
```

Then for definition:

```
bool operator<(const JobBid &left, const JobBid &right)
{
    // for you to fill in
}
```

You're missing a semicolon and the type for the argument.

EDIT: I also found another issue. You never define JBArray[0], so your `JBSmallest` should be `JBArray[1]`, not `JBArray[0]`.

Comment: I'm super confused, it gives me an error unless I provide 2 arguments for the definition. Should one argument be the array and one be the 'smallest' int? Looking at the site you linked, when they define the same operator they reference the variable in the class. So should my array list and smallest int also be defined in the class?

Comment: The way to call this function in your code would just be `JBArray[i] < smallest` like you have it, since both are of type `JobBid`.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed definition of "bool operator<(const smallest)"

The implementation of the operator could be

```
friend bool JobBid::operator<(const JobBid& smallest) {
     if(smallest.bid < this.bid && smallest.quote < this.quote)
           return true;
     else
           return false;
}
```

Comment: The friend declaration of the operator really depends on whether a class is going to be on the left- or right-hand side of the call. If a class is going to be on the right-hand side of the expression—and does not provide an implicit conversion to a type that can be compared with the left-hand side—you need to implement operator< as a separate function or as a friend of the class.